# Resizing an image to make it span the paperheight while trimming the width to fit paperwidth

Tags: graphics, crop, overpic

The title maybe says it all; I'd like to have a figure that first centers and resizes an image to fit the paperheight, and then trims the image to fit paperwidth.

Until now, I've done the trimming manually, but this is tedious and takes a long time.
The reasoning behind the paperwidth and height is that it's for the frontpage for our project, and it looks nice when printed both on paper and in pdf form.

Here is the code I've used until now (the manual way):

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % for the custom frontpage color
\usepackage[breakable,most,skins,listings]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{
top     =   0   cm,
bottom  =   0   cm,
right   =   0   cm,
left    =   0   cm
}

\begin{overpic}[trim=120pt 0pt 120pt 0pt, % <--- this is where the manual work is, the "problem"
            height=\paperheight]
            {frontpage.jpg} % <--- oversize image
    \put(0,0){\begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,               
        width=\paperwidth,      
        arc=0mm,                
        boxsep=25pt,            
        toprule=0pt,            
        leftrule=0pt,           
        bottomrule=0pt,         
        rightrule=0pt,          
        colframe=frontpagecolor,       
        colback=frontpagecolor,        
        opacityframe=.6,        
        opacityback=.6,         
        fontupper=\raggedright] 
        {\color{white}
            \Huge{\textbf{project title}}
        
            \Large{\textit{project subtitle}}\\
            \Large{\textit{project second line of subtitle}}
        
            \vspace{0.5cm}
        
            \large{
            Semester project \\\vspace{5pt}
            Group \\\vspace{5pt}
            2\textsuperscript{nd} Semester \\\vspace{5pt}
            University \\\vspace{5pt}
            date 2021
            }
        }
    \end{tcolorbox}
    }
    \put(60,85){\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{institution_logo.png}}
\end{overpic}

\end{document}
```

So, to clarify, what I'd like, is an image that 'crops itself' **after** being scaled to fit the paperheight.

Don't hesitate to ask questions or ask me to clarify something, it's in my interest to find a solution :)

Comment: can you upload the image

Answer (score 1):

You are already loading tikz, why not use it?  The image will automatically be trimmed to fit the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % for the custom frontpage color
\usepackage[breakable,most,skins,listings]{tcolorbox}

\newsavebox\tempbox

\begin{document}
\savebox\tempbox{\begin{tcolorbox}[% for tikzpicture inside another tikzpicture
        enhanced,               
        width=\paperwidth,      
        arc=0mm,                
        boxsep=25pt,            
        toprule=0pt,            
        leftrule=0pt,           
        bottomrule=0pt,         
        rightrule=0pt,          
        %colframe=frontpagecolor,% from overpic?      
        %colback=frontpagecolor,        
        opacityframe=.6,        
        opacityback=.6,         
        fontupper=\raggedright] 
        {\color{white}
            \Huge{\textbf{project title}}
        
            \Large{\textit{project subtitle}}\\
            \Large{\textit{project second line of subtitle}}
        
            \vspace{0.5cm}
        
            \large{
            Semester project \\\vspace{5pt}
            Group \\\vspace{5pt}
            2\textsuperscript{nd} Semester \\\vspace{5pt}
            University \\\vspace{5pt}
            date 2021
            }
        }%
    \end{tcolorbox}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[opacity=1] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
  \node[below] at (current page.north) {\usebox\tempbox};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %% gives dummy text for this file
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}
}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```